# Rails 3 - how to make a rebuild

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model, rebuild

I am making simple tree structure and in the tutorial is following:

> - Build cache: TreeNode.rebuild_depth_cache!

I never use this command, I tried to give this line into my controller (in the action that I have loaded in browser) and tried to refresh and hoped everything will be ok, but no.

> Cannot rebuild depth cache for model without depth caching.

(obviously I updated my model)

I tried to put this line into terminal window, but about error (command not found).

I am not sure where to put this command - into the controller (and there into an action) or into the terminal? I really don't know where this command should go, so I would like to ask you about the help...

Or, is everything other needed for run this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it in the Rails console: `rails c` in your terminal. And then run your command `TreeNode.rebuild_depth_cache!`.

The error is suspicious though. Are you sure you did not forget to call a class method in your model to make it act as a tree?

Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: Thanks Robin for your answer, except run this command in console is needed add to the model following: `has_ancestry :cache_depth =>true` and restart server.